# What is the name of song that plays in Naruto Episode 29?

Tags: naruto, music

What's the music in Episode 29 at 16:10 minutes?

Link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuQfSMoCtF0

Answer (score 2):

It's **Orochimaru's Battle/Fighting theme** (Orochimaru no Sentou theme) 
from Naruto Original Soundtrack 2.

Here's a Youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4N-Q14MvOI) for the full clip.